# Laravel Unknown at rule @tailwindcss(unknownAtRules)

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css

I installed a new Laravel project. I want to use Tailwind CSS and follow the instructions precisely as per the Tailwind website. When I run `npm run dev`, my resources/css/app.css file is not populated with Tailwind rules, and I still have only the three:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

With a warning of Unknown at rule @tailwindcss(unknownAtRules). I watched a video, and the video the person runs npm dev, and the app.css file is full of rules populated by Tailwind CSS.

Here is my directory structure for resources

[image]

**tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    content: [
        "./storage/framework/views/*.php",
        "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
        "./resources/**/*.js",
        "./resources/**/*.vue",
    ],
    theme: { extend: {} },
    plugins: [],
};
```

**Blade/View**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Add A Post</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
</head>

<body>
    @yield('content')
</body>

</html>
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require("laravel-mix");

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel applications. By default, we are compiling the CSS
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js").postCss(
    "resources/css/app.css",
    "public/css",
    [require("tailwindcss")]
);
```

Can anybody help me to use Tailwind and continue the project, please?

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0.5",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.0",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.14",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
        "axios": "^0.25",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.4.6",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "postcss-import": "^14.0.2"
    }
}
```

Comment: you have not used any tailwind class so after running there will be nothing

Comment: you can add `<h1 class="text-center">Heading</h1>` and re-run `npm run dev`

Comment: I added the line you told me and ran npm run dev and no change still the same warning and app.css still the same

Comment: can you show me your webpack.mix.js code?

Comment: I think you miss something.

Comment: I edited my question and added the code of that file

Comment: thank! you can see my answer below. add this line and re-run `npm run dev`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and solved by exchanging

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

with

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

and re-running

```
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 5):

"If you are working in VSCode, you need to disable the lint rule of unknownAtRules.

**RECOMMENDED FIX:**

1. Create .vscode at the root of your project
2. Create file named settings.json if not existing(*By default the modern version of VS code come with the settings.json file*).
3. Identify the filetype you are using for example css or scss
4. Create an empty json object {}
5. Inside json object add, `[FILE EXTENSION OF STEP 3].scss.lint.unknownAtRules": "ignore"`

Here is how the file will look like in the case of scss extension:

.vscode > settings.json

```
{
   "scss.lint.unknownAtRules": "ignore"
}
```

It helps you push the change in git and share the fix with the team.

**SECOND WAY:**

Do the same as explained above inside your VSCode Global settings.json. It will fix the problem for you but not for others using the same codebase. You can open the file by using

> Cmd+Shift+P

and then choosing **"Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)".**
Usually, it fixes the issue right away, but you can reload browser if needed.

Fix: For vue use `"css.lint.unknownAtRules": "ignore"`. Credits => @zijizhu"

I found the answer here [HERE](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/5258) thanks to: [Mr Fambo](https://github.com/mrfambo)

[More helpful link](https://flaviocopes.com/fix-unknown-at-rule-tailwind)

Comment: if instead you are  are not using any css preprocessor and just the css, the command looks similar to what @Diego as mentioned. Add this command and that should be able to fix the issue 

"css.lint.unknownAtRules": "ignore"

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the three rules are the key ones when you want to run Tailwind in your project. I am also currently learning Tailwind; my app.css file contains only those three rules, and I am good to go. I want to believe the rest of the configuration could be custom rules set. The major issue will be if Tailwind ain't responding at all when you are calling the tailwind CSS classes.

For my case, I had to manually copy the directive to my app.css file as they were not being populated automatically during the Tailwind CSS installation process.

Answer (score 0):

`webpack.min.js` missing below line.

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('postcss-import'), // add this line
        require('tailwindcss'),
    ]);
```

Comment: Now I get an error: Error: Cannot find module 'postcss-import'.

Comment: can you run `npm i postcss-import`

Comment: did what you said, ran npm run dev and no change the app.css still show the three @tailwind rules and warnings

Comment: what your laravel and laravel mix version? you can check it in compose.json and package.json

Comment: I edited the question again and added the information thanks @Lee